# Reporting Services: is there a way to print the sql server instance name on the report?

Tags: service, reporting, instance, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to print in a textbox the sql server instance name where a report is running.
For example on a textbox on the footer.
I'm using 2008 R2.

Comment: The name of the server with the SQL Server engine with your report data, or the SQL Server where your metadata DBs are, or the server where SSRS is running? They aren't always the same...

Comment: yes you are right. but supposing they are all the same?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... :-)

If they are all the same server (as per comment) then you may be able to use the [Globals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx) collection and the expression

```
 =Globals.ReportServerUrl
```

Typically, the URL will be distinct from the server name (eg via DNS/Host Headers) to allow for failover or load balancing or migrations

Comment: this does not give you the SQL SERVER INSTANCE name but actually the report server url

Comment: @gigi: yes, this is all you can do.